# I need help with a specific probability question

Tags: probability

I have a probability question.  The digits 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 8, and 8 are each written on a piece of paper and placed in a bag.  The pieces of paper are randomly drawn one at a time.  The digits are written down as they are drawn to create the eight digit number N.

I need to find the probability that N is divisible by 4.  My best guess is 50%? as there are four even number digits out of eight total for N to end in.

Next I must find the probability that N is prime?

and finally find the probability that N is a "palindrome"?

I have to look up what that even means.  I have no experience with probabilities so any useful information and help is very appreciated!!

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can consider the case where the digits are written in reverse order - this will greatly simplify the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

$50\%$ would be correct for the chance that the number is even.  To be a multiple of $4$ you not only need the last digit to be even, you need the number formed by the last two digits to be a multiple of $4$.  For the digits you have, that would mean ending in either $12, 28$ or in $88$.  Can you find the probability of each of those?
For the probability that $N$ is prime, do you know about the divisibility test for $3$?
A palindrome is a number that reads the same when reversed.  $11288211$ is one of the palindromes that can be formed with your digits.